# Вопросы по "лицензированию" объектов реального мира

Tags: лицензирование, юридические-аспекты

Дано: визуализация 3D планеты с разными уровнями детализации, от вида из космоса до 1 метра над поверхностью, где должны отображаться различные статические и динамические объекты, в соответствии с их реальным расположением и внешним видом: здания, дороги, деревья, автомобили и другие динамические объекты. (по принципу Google Earth)

Все перечисленные объекты добавляются пользователем (то есть разработчики не вносят туда элементы, в которых может упоминаться какой-либо бренд)

Разумеется, для отображения рельефа, водоемов, деревьев, и всего природного и культурного наследия ни у кого не нужно спрашивать разрешение, верно? Но как дела обстоят с теми объектами, которые имеют прямое отношение к стране?

Например:

- Дороги (авто/жд..)
- Здания и общественные места (также интерьер общественных зданий)
- Памятники
- Самолеты
- Животные

В общем то, что может увидеть любой гражданин (кроме военных баз:) ).

Или объекты, имеющие больше отношения к частным организациям:

- Дороги в пределах зон "не для каждого"
- Автомобили
- Вывески на магазинах и ТЦ
- Интерьер общественных зданий, которые не являются государственные

Темы об использовании Авто в комп играх широко распространены, откуда один вывод: покупка лицензии или выдача модели под вымышленным брендом.

Но все сводится к тому, что все эти детали добавляются пользователями. Как это в такому случае меняются условия по использованию достояния различных брендов/организаций ? Конечно, в ВК неким образом нарушается закон, когда пользователи ставят на аватарки изображения "Феррари" или загружают аудио, не спросив разрешения у авторов